# Upgrade to Django 4.0 has caused tests to fail even when the feature being tested works

Tags: django, django-tests, django-4.0

A bit of an odd one. I've upgraded from Django 3.2 to 4.0. A lot of my tests fail and they all fail where I'm testing the result of a form submission. However the forms themselves work fine when I test them using my browser. And all the tests fail in exactly the same way with the message `AssertionError: The form 'form' in context 166 does not contain the field 'date'` (obviously the field, form name and number are different in each test).

I've looked though the Django documents to see if the way forms should be tested has changed but I don't see any mention of anything that could have caused this.

Sample test:

```
    def test_expenses_new_and_edit_ye(self):
        """ Submits expense before and after ye date, then again with edit """
        self.client.force_login(User.objects.get_or_create(username='testuser')[0])
        # Redate the most recent YE to 10 days ago
        ye = JournalEntry.objects.filter(type='YE').order_by('-id')[0]
        ye.date = (datetime.today() - relativedelta(days=10))
        ye.save()
        # Try to submit into previous financial year
        date = (datetime.today() - relativedelta(days=10)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        response = self.client.post(reverse('journal:expenses_new'), {'date':date, 'account': 20, 'expense': 7, 'project': 1, 'store': 'Test store 223', 'amount': 10})
        self.assertFormError(response, 'form', 'date', 'Date must be within current financial year')
```

Sample output:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_expenses_new_and_edit_ye (journal.tests.test_main.ExpensesChecks)
Submits expense before and after ye date, then again with edit
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Philip\CodeRepos\Acacia2\journal\tests\test_main.py", line 1049, in test_expenses_new_and_edit_ye
    self.assertFormError(response, 'form', 'date', 'Date must be within current financial year')
  File "C:\Users\Philip\CodeRepos\Acacia2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 517, in assertFormError
    self.fail(
AssertionError: The form 'form' in context 166 does not contain the field 'date'
```

Comment: Ugh.  I have just stumbled across this issue too, and don't get why my `assertFormError` test is suddenly failing.  Did you get to the bottom of the issue?

Comment: I didn't get to the bottom of it. I left my Django at version 3 for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is that in Django 4.1 assertFormError don't get response in args
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/releases/4.1/#id2

Passing a response object and a form/formset name to SimpleTestCase.assertFormError() and assertFormsetError() is deprecated. Use:

```py
assertFormError(response.context['form_name'], …)
assertFormsetError(response.context['formset_name'], …)
```

your test will be correct:

```
self.assertFormError(response.context['form'], 'date', 'Date must be within current financial year')
```